# How to retrieve the camera origin/position from the view projection matrix? (OpenGL)

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math, projection-matrix, frustum

Is there any way to retrieve the camera origin/position from the view projection matrix? (OpenGL)

I'm trying to draw the camera's frustum and I have no problems calculating corners for the **Far** and the **Near** planes.

But I can't figure out how to retrieve a point that would represent the camera origin.

I was expecting to retrieve this by multiplying the Homogeneous clip-space coordinates:

```
glm::vec4(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f)
```

But I'm getting somewhat that looks to be like ~inverted camera position. (Marked as **X** in the screenshot) Included all the source code below.

[image]

```
    // Homogeneous points for source cube in clip-space.
    std::array<glm::vec4, 9> corners =
    {
        // Far plane
        glm::vec4(-1.f,-1.f, 1.f, 1.f), // bottom-left
        glm::vec4( 1.f,-1.f, 1.f, 1.f), // bottom-right
        glm::vec4( 1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f), // top-right
        glm::vec4(-1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f), // top-left

        // Near plane
        glm::vec4(-1.f,-1.f,-1.f, 1.f), // bottom-left
        glm::vec4( 1.f,-1.f,-1.f, 1.f), // bottom-right
        glm::vec4( 1.f, 1.f,-1.f, 1.f), // top-right
        glm::vec4(-1.f, 1.f,-1.f, 1.f), // top-left

        // Camera/screen center position.
    //  glm::vec4(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f) // EDIT
        glm::vec4(0.f, 0.f,-1.f, 0.f) // SOLVED
    };

    const auto invMatrix(glm::inverse(viewProjectionMatrix));

    for (U32 i = 0; i < corners.size(); i++)
    {
        corners[i] = invMatrix * corners[i]; // 4x4 * 4x1 matrix/vector multiplication.
        corners[i] /= corners[i].w; // Homogeneous to euclidean/cartesian conversion
    }

    // Far plane.
    this->AddLine(corners[0], corners[1], rColor);
    this->AddLine(corners[1], corners[2], rColor);
    this->AddLine(corners[2], corners[3], rColor);
    this->AddLine(corners[3], corners[0], rColor);

    // Near plane.
    this->AddLine(corners[4], corners[5], rColor);
    this->AddLine(corners[5], corners[6], rColor);
    this->AddLine(corners[6], corners[7], rColor);
    this->AddLine(corners[7], corners[4], rColor);

    // Connection from Near rectangle to the Far rectangle.
    this->AddLine(corners[0], corners[4], rColor);
    this->AddLine(corners[1], corners[5], rColor);
    this->AddLine(corners[2], corners[6], rColor);
    this->AddLine(corners[3], corners[7], rColor);

    // X
    this->AddLine(corners[4], corners[8], rColor);
    this->AddLine(corners[5], corners[8], rColor);
    this->AddLine(corners[6], corners[8], rColor);
    this->AddLine(corners[7], corners[8], rColor);
```

**[Solved]**

The problem was that I needed to use `glm::vec4(0.f, 0.f,-1.f, 0.f)` instead of `glm::vec4(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f)`.

Here are the desired results: [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the general case, if you only have a composed `viewProjection` matrix, you cannot deduce the camera origin from that. You will need additional information.

If you know that your projection is orthogonal (or any kind of *parallel* projection actually), there is no meaningful concept of a *camera position* anyway, and the origin is just some (more or less) arbitrary point you chose. To reconstruct it, you will need the parameters for the projection to decompose `viewProjection` into `view` and `projection`. There might be some shortcuts compared to doing a full construction of the `proj` but this will depend on the properties of the actual projection  parameters which you might know in advance / can assume.

In the case of a *perspective* projection, the situation is actually *simpler*: The center of projection will be projected to some point in infinity, but we exactly know its location in homogeneous clip space. It is just `proj * vec4(0,0,0,1)` for a typical projection matrix, which is just the last column of `proj`. Assuming default GL conventions, this will be something like `(0, 0, alpha, 0)`. The absolute value of alpha doesn't matter since this is only a direction anyway, just the sign will matter. Again, assuming default GL conventions, alpha will actually be negative, so the projection center will be transformed to `(0,0,-1,0)` in clip space. Therefore, you can simply inverte the calculations and go from clip space back to world space: `p_center = inverse(viewProj) * vec4(0,0,-1,0)`. Don't forget that the result is in homogeneous coordinates still, so you will need to divide by the resulting `w` to get a meaningful 3D coordinate.

Comment: Thank you! Using "glm::vec4(0.f, 0.f, -1.f, 0.f)" as suggested instead of my "glm::vec4(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f)" provided a valid camera's origin!